# How to dynamically allocate memory to multi-docker container AWS Elastic Beanstalk environment running Java applications

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, kotlin, amazon-ec2

I want to squeeze out every possible ounce of usage from the free elastic beanstalk tier.

My backend is built as a set of microservices (using ktor). I have **5 microservices** to be precise. All of these are dockerized and I'm trying to run them all on the same tiny **t2.micro** (free) elastic beanstalk instance with the **multi-docker image** environment

Java being java, it likes to idle around 200 MB RAM per docker container for even the most simplest microservice.

So, t2.micro gives you 1GB RAM. I have 5 microservice docker containers demanding at least 200 MB each = really close.

The trouble is, the memory is almost always hovering fiercely close to 100% nearly all the time.

So, is there a way to dynamically allocate memory to the docker containers depending on how much is free and how desperately one container needs it?

Say that one container is doing some heavy lifting while the others are mostly idle, I want to direct some RAM towards the container doing the heavy task and once the task is over, go back to equal RAM allocation per container.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `docker update --memory-reservation xxx <container>` to change the soft limit memory allocation for a container while it's running. Docker will gently push containers down to their soft limits when overall memory is low. So you could set soft limits of, say 150 MB for all your containers, and then bump one of them up when you know it has extra work to do.

The docker documentation on soft limits isn't that great, the kernel documentation for [CGroup Memory](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v1/memory.txt) explains it better.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into this more. Though ideally I would want a solution that, e.g: dynamically monitors the memory usage of multiple containers and gives more memory to the one that's running very close to the highest at any moment (in order to maximize performance). So, on a server, it wouldn't really be feasible to manually keep changing the limits as they might depend on cron job timing, traffic etc.

Comment: How is that different from having no memory management at all? If a JVM instance in one container is requesting memory allocation and another JVM instance in another container is holding onto unused heap space, the second JVM will give it up and let the first one have it...Right?

Comment: Is that so? Can you link to an authoritative source on the subject? In my experience, it seems to be a bit random. Sometimes an instance chooses to hold on to unused heap even if it starves the other instance, in which case the other instances starts using greater amount of paged memory, which slows things down.

Comment: This is starting to sound like more of a Java problem than a docker one. I haven't spent much time playing with them, but the -XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio and -XX:MinHeapFreeRatio are supposed to control how aggressively the JVM takes and gives memory from the OS. Maybe that would give you more consistent results? The [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/gctuning/factors-affecting-garbage-collection-performance.htm#JSGCT-GUID-7FB2D1D5-D75F-4AA1-A3B1-4A17F8FF97D0) on Garbage Collection have some details on those flags.

Comment: Yes, again that really only controls the starting static configuration that I can provide a java process, not how I can dynamically manage the memory allocated to different processes based on need.

Comment: "Need" is not a metric that the rest of the world can figure out for you, you have to tell us what that means. If "Need" means used heap size, use those flags will ensure the total heap size scales with the amount that's actually being used at any given time. Otherwise figure out what you actually want before you post a bountied question next time.